# React native audio recording and google speech API

Tags: react-native, audio, audio-recording, expo, google-speech-api

I'm using Expo's [Audio library](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio.html#audioencoder-) to record user speech, and sends them to Google Speech API for translation.

The only format that seems to match [Google speech's accepted encoding](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding) is `AMR_WB`. However, I am not able to find any React Native audio library to play `AMR_WB` files (`3gp` extension).

Allowing both translation and playing back of the user's recording is a core requirement.

Any suggestion on what I can do?

Comment: Hi there, what did you end up doing here? I am in a similar situation as yourself.